# How to find MAX(date) from BETWEEN(dates) in column 2 with DUPLICATES in column 1?

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, between, date-range, maxdate

I have a Database that has product names in column 1 and product release dates in column 2. I want to find 'old' products by their release date. However, I'm only interested in finding 'old' products that released a minimum of 1 year ago. I cannot make any edits to the original database infrastructure.

The table looks like this:

```
Product|   Release_Day
   A   |   2018-08-23
   A   |   2017-08-23
   A   |   2019-08-21
   B   |   2018-08-22
   B   |   2016-08-22
   B   |   2017-08-22
   C   |   2018-10-25
   C   |   2016-10-25
   C   |   2019-08-19
```

I have already tried multiple versions of DISTINCT, MAX, BETWEEN, >, <, etc.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product,MAX(release_day) as most_recent_release
FROM Product_Release
WHERE 
release_day between '2015-08-22' and '2018-08-22' 
and release_day not between '2018-08-23' and '2019-08-22'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY MAX(release_day) DESC
```

The expected results should not contain any products found by this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product,MAX(release_day) as most_recent_release
FROM Product_Release
WHERE 
release_day between '2018-08-23' and '2019-08-22'
AND product = A
GROUP BY 1
```

However, every check I complete returns a product from this date range.

This is the output of the initial query:

```
Product|Most_Recent_Release
   A   |   2018-08-23
   B   |   2018-08-22
   C   |   2015-10-25
```

And, for example, if I run the check query on Product A, I get this:

```
Product|Most_Recent_Release
   A   |   2019-08-21
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add "and release_day not between '2018-08-23' and '2019-08-22", when you have already "between" condition. The "not between" is NOT needed.

Comment: @GTodorov I only used NOT BETWEEN because when I just used BETWEEN, it wasn't recognizing a product with the same name that was released outside the range. The DB keeps the product name, but doesn't consider the version.

Comment: @scaisEdge I believe it is shown as DATETIME but is coming up as BOOLEAN.

Comment: It can't be `BOOLEAN`, that's just `1` or `0`.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `BOOLEAN` data type. Are you sure you're using MySQL?

Comment: @Barmar It is a web browser based SQL client

Comment: The question is tagged "mysql". What is the underlying database for this browser-based client?

Comment: PostgreSQL and Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING` to filter on `most_recent_release`

```
SELECT product, MAX(release_day) as most_recent_release
FROM Product_Release
GROUP BY product
HAVING most_recent_release < '2018-08-23'
ORDER BY most_recent_release DESC
```

There's no need to use `DISTINCT` when you use `GROUP BY` -- you can't get duplicates if there's only one row per product.

Comment: the platform I am using will not allow me to use DATE_SUB. Is this because the datatype in column 2 is BOOLEAN? Would an appropriate substitute look like this? ```HAVING MAX(release_day) < '2018-08-22'```?

Comment: I got rid of `DATE_SUB`. How can `most_recent_release` be boolean?

Comment: When I tried the other answer using SUM, it returned an error message that said "unknown: SUM(Boolean)".